# How i can do custom border for matrix in css

Tags: html, css, border

```
<table style="float:left;">
    <tr>
        <td><input id="c11" placeholder="c1,1" class="matr_c" readonly></td>
        <td><input id="c12" placeholder="c1,2" class="matr_c" readonly></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input id="c21" placeholder="c2,1" class="matr_c" readonly></td>
        <td><input id="c22" placeholder="c2,2" class="matr_c" readonly></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I have a code of some matrix in html and css. It looks like this picture now.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/4HJJ3.png

But I want to add some border like this.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/BKvGP.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `pseudo` element `:before` and `:after` for giving border

```css
table {
  position: relative;
}
table:before,
table:after {
  content: '';
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  border-color: black;
  border-style: solid;
  width: 10px;
  top: -1px;
}
table:before {
  left: -2px;
  border-width: 2px 0px 2px 2px;
}
table:after {
  right: -2px;
  border-width: 2px 2px 2px 0px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input id="c11" placeholder="c1,1" class="matr_c" readonly>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input id="c12" placeholder="c1,2" class="matr_c" readonly>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input id="c21" placeholder="c2,1" class="matr_c" readonly>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input id="c22" placeholder="c2,2" class="matr_c" readonly>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

1- You can add a background image for the table, by these borders, and style the table.

OR:

2- You can put two divs around the table from the left and the right, then give the a background image for each div with one border image, also let the divs have an absolute position.